# Converse.js and OpenFire passwordless authentication (certificates)

Tags: xmpp, openfire, converse.js

I want to enable passwordless authentication in Converse.js, using CA signed certificates, but I am having troubles with it. Here is what I've done:

- Added the CA in the truststore for OpenFire;
- Added the OpenFire certificate in its keystore;
- Created a client valid and signed certificate.

I have also set some properties in the OpenFire server, i.e., `sasl.mechs:  EXTERNAL`, `xmpp.client.certificate.verify: true` and `xmpp.client.cert.policy: wanted`.

My converse script looks like:

```
converse.initialize({
    bosh_service_url: 'https://localhost:7443/http-bind/',
    authentication: 'external',
    show_controlbox_by_default: true,
    debug: true,
});
```

As from this [blog post](https://opkode.com/blog/strophe_converse_sasl_external/), I expected the browser to request the user to provide the certificate with a popup, but I keep getting:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

Any help will be appreciated.