# External authentication on Converse.js

Tags: converse.js

I am trying  to authenticate my Converse.js client to theOpenfire server using TLS. I have configured the server and the client for external authentication, but when trying to connect, it stays connecting forever, not returning error messages. Below is the console log with debug info:

```
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: request id 3.0 state changed to 1
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: request id 3.1 state changed to 2
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: request id 3.1 state changed to 3
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: request id 3.1 state changed to 4
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: removing request
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: _throttledRequestHandler called with 0 requests
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: request id 3 should now be removed
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: request id 3.1 got 200
converse.js:48507 INFO: _connect_cb was called
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: _throttledRequestHandler called with 1 requests
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: request id 4.0 posting
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: request id 4.0 state changed to 1
converse.js:43863 XHR finished loading: POST "https://localhost:7443/http-bind/".
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: request id 4.1 state changed to 2
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: request id 4.1 state changed to 3
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: request id 4.1 state changed to 4
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: removing request
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: _throttledRequestHandler called with 0 requests
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: request id 4 should now be removed
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: request id 4.1 got 200
converse.js:48507 INFO: _connect_cb was called
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: _throttledRequestHandler called with 1 requests
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: request id 5.0 posting
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: request id 5.0 state changed to 1
converse.js:43863 XHR finished loading: POST "https://localhost:7443/http-bind/".
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: request id 5.1 state changed to 2
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: request id 5.1 state changed to 3
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: request id 5.1 state changed to 4
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: removing request
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: _throttledRequestHandler called with 0 requests
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: request id 5 should now be removed
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: request id 5.1 got 200
converse.js:43863 XHR finished loading: POST "https://localhost:7443/http-bind/".
converse.js:48507 INFO: _connect_cb was called
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: _throttledRequestHandler called with 1 requests
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: request id 6.0 posting
converse.js:48505 DEBUG: request id 6.0 state changed to 1
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for your other problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49542252/converse-js-and-openfire-passwordless-authentication-certificates

Comment: The debug output you pasted doesn't provide any useful information. Try checking your OpenFire log ouput for info.

Comment: I did. I also had a self-signed certificate in the Keystore of OpenFIre, and deleting it solved my first problem. For your second question, the OpenFire logs do not show any related message either

Comment: Instead of leaving your original question unanswered, you should answer it yourself with your solution so that other people also benefit.